# data.push is not working for jquery

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I am sending data by post method of jquery. Data is collected from an form by serializeArray() method by following:

```
$("body").on("click",".submit",function(event){
 var data = $('#formid').serializeArray();
 data.push({name:'yourname'});
     $.post(url,
     data,function(callbackdata){
      $("#result").html(callbackdata).show();
    });
});
```

When I process the post data in php like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
```

I found all the serialized data acquired from that form, but the added extra data by data.push is not found. instead it is showing undefined like this:

```
username : mr.X
address : Bangladesh
ID no : 225068
undefined :
```

why the data.push is not working for me?
Please give me a solution.

Comment: Use your browsers developer tools and see what is being sent to the server

Comment: @Brett It does not matter because his push statement is not working and that is before post method.

Comment: @RohitArora lol, really? No wonder you have 64 answers and only ~900 rep, you can't even read the question properly.

Comment: @Brett Check out the answer. Doesn't seem to relate with server. and that was too obvious to know that you do not have to mess with server right now or what is being sent to server first if you have problem in javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this you need to pass `value` as well:-

```
 var data = $('#formid').serializeArray();
  data.push({name: 'keyname', value: 'yourvalue'});
```